# I cannot login after installing the wp-login timeout setting plugin

Tags: plugins, login

I am not very experienced with Wordpress, however I installed the above plugin and now I cannot log in. When I try to log in it just refreshes and asks for my password again. The password is correct it just refreshes the page.

I think what I did with the plugin once it installed is I set the time as 0 seconds (default was 600 seconds). Please can anyone help!?

I have deleted all cookies and browser history, deleted the plug in files, tried different logins of other people, different browsers and restarted my computer but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the plugin folder of your plugin via FTP, then the plugin gets deactivated. You can find it in `/wp-content/plugins/`. For exampre rename it to `wp-login-timeout-settings-xxx`, so you can login, then rename it to the original name, activate it again and change the settings.

Comment: How do I rename it via FTP? Sorry what does that mean?

Comment: I deleted the folder, so wouldn't you think that would deactivate it?

Comment: Renaming depends on the FTP Client, but normally right click on the folder and then "rename".  So can you now login again?